# Javascript regex to replace quotes without front backslash

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm looking for javascript regex to replace quotes without front backslash.

For example:

```
'"'.replace(xxx, yyy); -> '\"'
'\"'.replace(xxx, yyy); -> '\"'
'\\"'.replace(xxx, yyy); -> '\\\"'
```

Currently, I did the following, but I believe there is a better way.

```
content = content.replace(/"/g, '\\"');
content = content.replace(/\\\\"/g, '\\"');
```

Comment: Can you give an example of input and expected result?

Comment: I'm very tempted to ask "Why do you need this?" and "What are you *actually* trying to do?". This is a very strange thing to want to do and smells of vulnerabilities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand the question you would like to replace only those quotes that are not proceeded with the backslash character. For this you could use below [regex](https://regex101.com/r/jFsTxe/1)

```js
var str = 'this"quote but not \"this one';
console.log(str.replace(/(([^\\])(["]))/g, "$2\\$3"));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
JSON.stringify('abc " def')
```

returns

```
"abc \" \" def"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to replace all the `'"'` with `'\"'`,

then

`var replacedString = 'string with " " quotes'.replace(/"/g,'\\\"');`

should work.